# Reduce upload button size in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, imagebutton

I created a button to upload a file with an icon in order to mask the input text box and have just one button. The problem is that my button takes all the width of the div. I would like the two button are side by side. But, when I modify the .btn-file, the select dialog is broken and so, It doesn't appears.
This is the div :

```
<div id="mydiv">
  A text <br>
  An other text
  <form id="test">
    <span class="btn btn-block btn-file">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="exampleInputFile" file-model="customer.file" on-file-change="Submit">
    </span>
  </form>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
</div>
```

This it the CSS :

```
.btn-file {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-file input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}
```

Can you help me to align the two buttons and reduce the size of the upload button ? Thanks.

Comment: you can append the input element after clicking the icon then pass click to the input :)

Comment: What do you want to display icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make inline to the span that contains file upload button.

I modified your demo here - https://plnkr.co/edit/cYpho3SPeRV4NqqGOuHw?p=preview

```css
.btn-file {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-file input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mydiv">
      A text <br>
      An other text
      <form id="test">
        <span class="btn btn-block btn-file" style="display:inline">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i>
          <input type="file" name="file" id="exampleInputFile" file-model="customer.file" on-file-change="Submit">
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the class btn-block on the outer span -- which is making it display in block mode, hence why it's taking up all the width available. Remove that class if you don't want this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks it works, how can I reduce the width of the form ? It take all the width page and if I wrapp it in a div and set a max-width: 40px; for example, it doesn't works.